# Get test parameters from specific test run

Tags: c#, tfs, microsoft-test-manager

A user needs to look up a specific test run of an automated test case. Using the TFS C# code libraries I've been able to pull most of the test data related to the result of the test run but I can't seem to get the parameters that were used for that test run.

So far I have the following working for me:

```
//get the individual test run OBJECT
ITestRun testRunData = proj.TestRuns.Find(<Test Run ID>); 

//get the data from the case as it is saved in TFS now
DataSet testData = proj.TestCases.Find(<Test Case ID>).Data;
```

Is there any graceful way get the data that was passed in for a specific test run?

Comment: Hi Reed, any update for this issue? Have you figured it out?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT Yep! Upon test execution, I get the DataTable from the rows of parameters of all iterations and export it to an XML as an attachment. From there I can use the TFS API to get the TestRun/TestResult and the associated attachments - and therefore the parameters that were passed in at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is not any test parameters for a specific test run. You could double confirm this info in your MTM with opening a test run.

Another way is through [Rest API-- Test runs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/runs#get-a-test-run), it will also obtain all related data for a  test run. However there is not any test parameters in a test run.

You could only get the parameters for a **test case**, such through test data.

Comment: Yep, I saw that in the documentation as well. What I've done is saved an XML structure of the input parameters at execution as an attachment. That way a user can see what parameters were used when looking back at previous test runs.

Comment: @Reed Are you using a  Data-Driven test such as this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182527.aspx),   which parameters in a test run you would like to get, could  you  add a screenshot show this. If you are using the  driven test, it's also not able to get the parameters from a particular test run. You could try to get the parameters from a test result.